# wampserver services query of 2 running from 3 services

Tags: wampserver

I have one query when start my wampserver is showing me a yellow icon with 2 services is running from three and I am not able to open phpadmin even, I set up new port, start, install services but no solution I can find. How to solve it?

Comment: Look at the error logs

Comment: [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66440719/2310830)