# wampserver 2 out of 3 services

Tags: service, wampserver

I have joomla installed as one of half a dozen local wampserver projects (I use joomla as a web-page management portal to taskmanage everything I do).
Joomla works, so phpadmin is working and so must be php.
But I continually get 2 out of 3 services running.
I've tried the "mysqlold" solution in task manager and nothing changes.
Given the above and what is working, what service isn't running and what can I do to make it so?
I apologise for the newbie nature of the question, but I've only just started using wampserver.

Comment: If you are doing Joomla work, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 2):

Well the 3 services that WAMPServer is talking about are

1. Apache
2. MySQL Server
3. mariaDB Server

Now its quite legitimate to have only Apache and MySQL running, or Apache and mariaDB.

If you have stopped lets say `mariaDB` then you would see the tooltip

```
"2 of 3 services running"
```

but as you only want Apache and MySQL that would be fine. *NOTE* If you have stopped one of the services the WAMPServer icon will be Orange instead of Green.

Its rare you want to have MySQL and mariaDB running at the same time, its unlikely one site would require both so it is possible to STOP one of the databases. If you have, intensionally or accidentally done this you will see a **black square** beside the `Services Administration wampmariadb64` menu line

[image]

And if the service is started you will see a **Green Tick**

[image]

It is also possible to turn off one of the database servers completely.

Using the wampmanager menu

```
**right click**->Wamp Settings->Allow MariaDB
```

You should see 2 lines

1. Allow MySQL
2. Allow mariaDB

[image]

If these 2 lines have a Green Tick beside them then that database's service should be installed, if not then that database service has been uninstalled. If you click "Allow XXXX" then it will toggle that service to or from installed. If you uninstall one, the tool tip that you get when hovering over the wampmanager icon will say

```
"2 of 2 serives started"
```

assuming there are no other issues :)

Comment: HUGE THANK YOU for time, patience and effort in typing that answer :-)

Comment: But did it help?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issues and tried a lot of things. Finally I fixed it using below instructions:

1. Uninstall wamp and delete wamp directory
2. Install VC 16 package
3. Install wamp again and it will work like a charm